# Indeterminate forms with continued radicals

Tags: calculus, limits

I am interested in the limit
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} \cfrac{\sin \left(  \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x + \ldots}}} \right)}{\sqrt{x}}$$

My intuition is the limit is 1.

It seems we have $\sin\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{\sqrt{1+4x}}{2}\right)$ in the numerator so that the limit would be $\frac{1}{0^+}$ or infinity.

It appears there is some kind of special discontinuity at $x=0$. There is no right continuity in the continued radical at $x=0$. It should be 0 not 1.

l'Hopital's rule cannot be applied to this problem? Can you take the limit at $x=0$ instead?

Are there any sophisticated ideas on this problem?

Comment: The limit is indeed undefined. Since it is understood that the limit of the infinite recursion sequence is taken first, $f(0)$ will tend to the stable fixed point of $1$ as $x\to 0$ rather than to the unstable fixed point of $0$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT.-$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x + \ldots}}}=0$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin\left( \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x + \ldots}}}\right)}{ \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x + \ldots}}}}=1$$
Put $M= \sqrt{x+\sqrt{x+\sqrt{x + \ldots}}}$ so you have
$$\frac{\sin(M)}{\sqrt x}=\frac{\sin(M)}{M}\cdot\frac{M}{\sqrt x}$$
But $$\frac{M}{\sqrt x}=\sqrt{1+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^2}+\sqrt{\frac{x}{x^4} + \ldots}}}$$ from which $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{M}{\sqrt x}=\infty$$ Consequently
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{\sin(M)}{M}\cdot\frac{\sin(M)}{\sqrt x}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}1\cdot\frac{\sin(M)}{\sqrt x}=\infty$$

Comment: Yes, $\lim_{x \to 0+} \cfrac{\sin(M)}{M}$ is not equal to one because it is continuous there and equal to $\sin(1)/0$